# Same operations on variables with identical types in the same scope take different time in the same C code

Tags: c, performance, optimization

Have seen similar questions, but they relate to cache misses or code reordering. Nothing of that happens in my case.

The code is very simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned char a, b;
    int i;

    clock_t before = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        a *= 2;
        b *= 2;
    }
    printf("elapsed: %lu\n", clock() - before);

    before = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        a *= 2;
        a *= 2;
    }    
    printf("elapsed: %lu\n", clock() - before);
}
```

So there are two vars `a` and `b`, and I do something with them (it's not really important what to do).
The first loop modifies `a` and `b`, and the second loop modifies `a` only. Can be `b` only as well, does not matter.

The second loops takes roughly twice the time.

The assembly lines for `a *= 2` and `b *= 2` look like this:

```
    sal BYTE PTR -1[rbp]
    sal BYTE PTR -2[rbp]
```

And for the second loop they look like this:

```
    sal BYTE PTR -2[rbp]
    sal BYTE PTR -2[rbp]
```

As you can see, number of operations is the same, operations are the same, memory access is the same, and there could not be a cache miss. The only difference is between `-1[rbp]` and `-2[rbp]`.

So why the second loop takes TWICE the time? I can only guess that it is somehow related to accessing the same var in two consecutive operations. I can imagine that the first operation needs some time to complete before the second one can get access to the same var. Whereas in the first loop the first operation is performed on one var and the second operation is performed on another var so they are independent and don't have to wait one another. But that should imply some micro-parallelism on CPU level. Is that true?

You can also run the program online here:
https://onlinegdb.com/27qixKsWP

Comment: Are you compiling with max optimization for speed?

Comment: `But that should imply some micro-parallelism on CPU level. Is that true?` Yes.

Comment: I would assume the two operations on `a` in the second loop to be optimized into _one_ though

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, I compile to get identical operations in both cases to compare time, that is the whole point. The two ops on ```a``` are not optimized into one.

Comment: [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/h5qID9I9b-wZsZ1gtkZ1jnk9_6s) shows that the second loop is twice as fast if you compile it as you should when benchmarking

Comment: Benchmarking unoptimized code is not useful.  Both loops will likely be removed under optimization as they produce no observable results.

Comment: The point is not in code optimization. If you see two identical ops that take different time, you need to know why.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica please help me create the proper title

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think it's ok :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first loop can be pipelined, because the two instructions are operating on different memory locations. Both multiplications can be done at the same time.

The second loop operates on the same memory location, so the second multiplication has to wait for the first one to finish.

Comment: -O0 adds so much noise

Comment: In other words: *Identical operations on identical vars*... nope, identical operations, but not on identical vars.

Comment: I think they meant "vars with identical types in the same scope". They're not actually the same variables.

Comment: -1[rbp] and -2[rbp] are identical in terms of machine instruction structure and memory access type, they are different memory locations though, but that is actually the answer to my question.